# WriteableBitmap to BitmapFrame convertation

Tags: c#

Is there some painless convertation?
I have googled this sample:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{//WriteableBitmap wb defined before
    wb.SaveJpeg(ms, (int)image1.Width, (int)image1.Height, 0, 100);
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(ms);
}
```

But wb HAS NO SaveJpeg method! (using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; using System.Windows.Media;)
and bmp HAS NO SetSource =(

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for that.

```
var bf = BitmapFrame.Create(wb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `WriteableBitmap` directly into `BitmapFrame.Create()`. Then, you can save the `BitmapFrame` as a JPEG using `JpegBitmapEncoder`:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
JpegBitmapEncoder enc = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wb));
enc.Save(ms);
```

If you want to resize the image before saving, I recommend using [WriteableBitmapEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx/), available in the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio. Here is how it is used:

```
WriteableBitmap newWB = wb.Resize(256, 256, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
```